# How to implement a draggable MKPointAnnotation using Swift (IOS)?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm noob in ios and I need implement a draggable `MKPointAnnotation` in a `MKMapView` using swift. I need an example. I now implement the `MKMapView` and add a `MKPointAnnotation` in the map (addAnnotation).

My english is bad, help me please!

I found this **[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW22)**,but I didn't understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create a custom class, derived from MKMapView. This class has to implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol.

Then you need 2 steps: Create the annotation object and create a view for that annotation.

**Create Annotation:**

Somewhere in your code, depends on your needs:

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.setCoordinate(location)  // your location here
annotation.title = "My Title"
annotation.subtitle = "My Subtitle"

self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

**Create the annotation View**

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if annotation is MKPointAnnotation {
        let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")

        pinAnnotationView.pinColor = .Purple
        pinAnnotationView.draggable = true
        pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
        pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

        return pinAnnotationView
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is my example code. This code allows you to long press on the map to add a Point and to drag that point until you release your finger from the screen. Also take a look to the gestureRecognizer that you have to add on the map view. Hope this could helps you.

```
class TravelLocationMapController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

var dragPin: MKPointAnnotation!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
    let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addPin:")
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

func addPin(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(mapView)
    let newCoordinates = mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
    if dragPin != nil {
        dragPin.coordinate = newCoordinates
    }

    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        dragPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        dragPin.coordinate = newCoordinates
        mapView.addAnnotation(dragPin)
    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {            
        dragPin = nil
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKPointAnnotation {
        let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")

        pinAnnotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

        return pinAnnotationView
    }
    return nil
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let lat = view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude
    let long = view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude

    print("Clic pin lat \(lat) long \(long)")

}
```

Comment: Super, thanks!  You should try to get an existing ``MKPinAnnotationView`` with ``mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("myPin")`` in ``mapView(_:viewForAnnotation)``, though.